# Quicksight query two tables has problem with left join

Tags: left-join, amazon-quicksight

I have a bad result with using query in Quicksight.

I have one table with campaign, if I query just on this table, it is ok; I have all campaigns in my list. But when I use left join, i have just the results which match with join table.

Is this normal?

I have already tried all join possibilities and it is the same.

Comment: please share your code and what you have done so far.

Comment: Please also read [ask].